# Spark Shell with Cygwin on Windows 7 just freezes after command

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I downloaded `spark 2.2.1` on windows 7 version  `spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7.` and running shell command via `cygwin`. when i am running spark shell by command  `./spark-shell.cmd`
it just freezes nothing happens. Below is the history of the commands.

```
munish@munish-PC /cygdrive/e/installer/newSpark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
$ ls

beeline              load-spark-env.cmd  pyspark2.cmd     spark-class.cmd   sparkR2.cmd       spark-sql
beeline.cmd          load-spark-env.sh   run-example      spark-class2.cmd  spark-shell       spark-submit
find-spark-home      pyspark             run-example.cmd  sparkR            spark-shell.cmd   spark-submit.cmd
find-spark-home.cmd  pyspark.cmd         spark-class      sparkR.cmd        spark-shell2.cmd  spark-submit2.cmd

munish@munish-PC /cygdrive/e/installer/newSpark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
$ ./spark-shell
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main

munish@munish-PC /cygdrive/e/installer/newSpark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin


$ ./spark-shell.cmd

Using Spark's default log4j profile: `org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties`

Setting default log level to "WARN".

To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

Spark context Web UI available at http://169.254.168.53:4040

Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1520766070803).

Spark session available as 'spark'.

Welcome to

      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.1
      /_/


Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val a = Array("a", "b")
```

nothing happens after this even for hours. Any pointers please. Any env variable to set, which i am missing ?

thanks

Comment: try executing from command prompt rather than cygwin

Comment: does the issue resolved ?